# Trouble setting language

Tags: python, locale, language-support

I am really struggling with this language issue.

I went to `System->Administration->Language Support` and moved Turkish (Türkçe) to the top. Then I clicked "Apply System-wide" and restarted.

However, after restarting, `echo $LANG` reported `en_US.utf8`, so I logged out and back in - and now it reports `tr_CY.utf8`.

Now here's the problem:

- I have a file 'xxx.po' in `/usr/share/locale/tr_CY/LC_MESSAGES`
- I run the following Python code:

  ```
  import gettext


  gettext.bindtextdomain("xxx","/usr/share/locale")
  gettext.textdomain("xxx")
  tr = gettext.translation("xxx",
                           "/usr/share/locale",
                           ["tr_CY"],
                           fallback=True)


  print tr.gettext("sample")
  ```

Although 'sample' should be translated, it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That **tr_CY** (means Cypriot Turkish) has nothing to do with even a few hundred thousand Turk living in Cyprus. It should be **tr_TR** . Maybe after this modification, it works. Even if it works or not after modification, **tr_CY** is **wrong**, it should be **tr_TR** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a file 'xxx.po' in /usr/share/locale/tr_CY/LC_MESSAGES

The files in `/usr/share/locale/<LANG>/LC_MESSAGES` need to be in a binary format ('.mo' extension).

You achieve that by running `msgfmt` on the '.po' file:

`msgfmt -c -v -o OUTPUT.mo LANG.po`

- `-c` checks the po file format,
- `-v` is for detailed output,
- `-o OUTPUT.mo` specifies the output file, where OUTPUT should be the name you used in 'bindtextdomain' and 'textdomain',
- `LANG.po` the translation file.